StaleElementReferenceException Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
for card in cards:
    time.sleep(2)
    card.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="VacancyHeader"]/div[3]/div[1]/a')
    button.click()
    time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\VscodeFiles\PYTHON\SELENIUM-ENV\DISPARA-CURRICULO\env\main.py", line 44, in <module>     card.click()   File "D:\VscodeFiles\PYTHON\SELENIUM-ENV\DISPARA-CURRICULO\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 94, in click     self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)   File "D:\VscodeFiles\PYTHON\SELENIUM-ENV\DISPARA-CURRICULO\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute     return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "D:\VscodeFiles\PYTHON\SELENIUM-ENV\DISPARA-CURRICULO\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",  line 347, in execute     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "D:\VscodeFiles\PYTHON\SELENIUM-ENV\DISPARA-CURRICULO\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found           (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.105); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception Stacktrace:         GetHandleVerifier [0x00F54CC3+225091]         (No symbol) [0x00E84E11]         (No symbol) [0x00D29A7A]         (No symbol) [0x00D35691]         (No symbol) [0x00D35CEE]         (No symbol) [0x00D2E86B]         (No symbol) [0x00D2CF05]         (No symbol) [0x00D2F862]         (No symbol) [0x00D2F8E0]         (No symbol) [0x00D62F31]         (No symbol) [0x00D596B2]         (No symbol) [0x00D7F55C]         (No symbol) [0x00D5930E]         (No symbol) [0x00D7F7F4]         (No symbol) [0x00D95CB0]         (No symbol) [0x00D7F2F6]         (No symbol) [0x00D579B9]         (No symbol) [0x00D5879D]         sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013C9A63+4064547]         sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013D106A+4094762]         sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x013CB968+4072488]         sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x010CC9C9+930953]         (No symbol) [0x00E907E4]         (No symbol) [0x00E8AD08]         (No symbol) [0x00E8AE31]         (No symbol) [0x00E7CAA0]         BaseThreadInitThunk [0x754BFCC9+25]         RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76EC7C5E+286]         RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76EC7C2E+238]

I have already tried several famous solutions here on stack overflow such as stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document and I was not successful in fixing the mistake

the click()s are probably causing DOM updates.  Don't do that while iterating the webelement reference array.
